# UrlFetchApp.fetchAll "Exception: ScriptError Exception: Address unavailable" error raised randomly

Tags: google-apps-script

I often perform some data-processing tasks, which involve processing ~1 k urls(polling various api).

Recently I've started to use UrlFetchApp.fetchAll often, splitting requests into chunks by 5-50 urls.

The problem is that sometimes, absolutely randomly I get this error:

```
Exception: ScriptError Exception: Address unavailable: https://...
```

it's always different urls/domains, which are fine by themselves.

If anyone had run into this too, can you explain what does this error mean and how do you handle this?

Comment: I have run into this error too.  The challenge here is that it seems to happen on one of the many requests that you pass in the array, at random.  Instead of `fetchAll()` handling this and returning a failure item in the response array for that fetch only (and continuing on), it throws an error for the entire fetchAll() and stops execution.  A try catch block is unhelpful since it won't have information about the calls that succeeded.  Exponential backoff would result in (possibly non-idempotent) duplicate API calls.  Anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

The one that causes your issue might probably be blocked IP addresses. Google uses different IPs to communicate to the server.

Sometimes, the server blocks one or more of these Google owned IPs causing the address unavailable error.

Every request uses different IPs to communicate so when we are dealing with large numbers of urls, there is a probability that we will encounter a blocked IP address, thus resulting into address unavailable (Law of Large Numbers).

I also want to add that there are also instances that certain sites are blocking requests made from `UrlFetchApp`

These issues are all on the side of the url you are trying to access or Google's so I'm not sure if there is a way to work around this but that's all what I am seeing that causes your issue.

Comment: Script is run server-side, why any browser limits should apply there?

Comment: Sorry about that @roma, I included some possible causes on the issue itself previously. Edited the answer and only written what could be the causes your script encounters. If it may not be the answer you need or hope to have, I certainly apologize.